# Need help returning/passing multiple arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have an assignment in my computer science class where I am writing a program that will need to return multiple array. Technically I could do this just fine, but the way the assignment is set up make it difficult for me to gauge certain things.

Basically, I have to declare two arrays and a variable in the `main()` function and send them to a function called `input()`.

`Input()` will take these three things, which are `NumberOfYears`, `Year[NumberOfYears]`,`DataForYear[NumberOfYears]`. `NumberOfYears` will be taken using a `scanf()`, and that will determine how many times a `for()` loop runs that will use a `scanf()` for `Year[]` and `DataForYear[]`. `Year[]` and `DataForYear[]` must use the same `scanf()` statement, which I know how to do.

After taking all of this, I need to create a function called `output()` which will basically `printf()` all of the values the user just gave me (being `Year[]` and `DataForYear[]`). However, I need a way to return both arrays to the main function, as well as `NumberOfYears`. I have heard this can be done using something called structs, however we have not learned this yet and I am sure my instructor will not approve.

The instructor's notes suggested that only `NumberOfYears` should be returned to the main function, but I simply do not see how this is possible. If you have a way that I can pass of these things along to `output()` without having to return them, that would be great to. Otherwise, I just need some sort of way to do this, and the rest of program is history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, anytime you pass an 'array', you actually pass a pointer.  So your return type can be something like `int*`, depending on the type of the array you need to pass back.  You can use `&x` to get the address of variable `x` (e.g. the first element of your array) if necessary.

The other possibility is that since you're passing a pointer you don't even need to actually return it.  You can modify your array inside the `input` function and then see it's changed afterward in `main` without doing more work.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying that when you change an array in another function, that it automatically changes itself in the main function (the function it was first declared in) as well? Does this work even if you intialize it as a different name in the other function?

Comment: Yes.  When you declare an array like  int myarray[5] it creates five little spaces for numbers.  When you pass that array to a function, you only pass the *location* of the first element.  Then the function manipulates the values in those locations.  So, when you get back to the calling function, it sees those 5 locations with any of the manipulations done by that function call.  It doesn't matter what you name the array in the function definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That pretty much solves all of my problems, then. :)

Answer (score 1):

Functions can return via their parameters as well as their return:

```
int doMyThing( int *somethingElse ) {
    *somethingElse = 40;
    return 2;
}

int main( void ) {
    int a;
    int b = doMyThing( &a );
    printf( stdout, "%d\n", a + b ); // prints "42"
}
```

And you can extend that to arrays by using `int **somethingElse`, or whatever you need.

Comment: (and, for clarity, that will print out 42)

Comment: Wow, I actually didn't know that! I don't believe we've covered that yet, but I'm sure this will definitely help in the future.